# CSS Rule Set not apply correctly

Tags: css, stylesheet, rules

Alright, heres the css I'm working with.

```
input{
border: 2px solid #000;
background-color: #808080;
color: #fff;
}
```

As far as I'm aware, this should effect every input thats on a page that this stylesheet is linked too.

However, it seems to only change the font color and nothing else. Unless I reference a form by id, then it applys the entire set of rules.

The fact that it changes the font color shows that it is indeed linking. But why would it only effect the font color and nothing else till I do it by id?

There are no other stylesheets that would override it, no embedded or inline styles either.

Comment: Everything you're saying indicates that there are some other styles that have a greater specificity than the one above. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: "There are no other stylesheets that would override it" are you sure?

Comment: I am absolutely sure. I have no embedded css or inline css. And I only have the one stylesheet and in that stylesheet this is the only group that effects inputs. In fact, the only other background color at all is the one on the container.

Answer (score 3):

im not a master of css but to me it looks like the "**user agent stylesheet**"  are a little more specific for example chrome would use selectors like `input[type="password"], input[type="search"], isindex` for the default styles.

so just by using a generic descendant selector you should be able to bypass that try `body input` or `form input`

### edit

you can always open firebug inspect the input and see how the styles apply/override.

Comment: No luck. I tried that already. Tried it again just to make sure but no joy unfortunatly

Comment: can you create a fiddle example?

Comment: I've never used fiddle before but I gave it a shot. When I plug it all in it shows it working fine. However that's not how it appears when I test it on my own computer. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/MtBHE/

Comment: is it possible that you have a syntax error in your css? (like a missing colon or semi-colon)

Comment: I just went through it line by line to check. I dont see anything missing.

Comment: open firebug and inspect the input see how the styles apply/override.

Comment: You sir, are a god. There was one background color I missed and I didn't even realize that my form was inside that class. Once I found it a closer inspection revealed the problem. Thanks man!